# Removing a column from a DictField in MongoDB [Flask + MongoEngine]

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I need to remove a particular column (in this case "Paper ID") from a DictField (in this case "content") in all documents. The corresponding mongo-shell script for the same is

```
db.list_input_file.update({},{$unset:{"content.Paper ID":1}}, false, true);
```

How do I write the same thing using MongoEngine assuming that my model class is named JListInputFile. The [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates) for the same isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is a space in the field name meaning you can't pass it as a keyword argument eg:

```
JListInputFile.objects.update(unset__content__Paper ID=1)
```

Does using a dictionary kwargs work:

```
JListInputFile.objects.update(**{"unset__content__Paper ID": 1})
```

Comment: I feel silly asking this, I thought once I figured how to remove a column, renaming it would have a similar construct. But unfortunately, there's no construct called rename. Could you help me with a sample rename query as well?

Comment: could you help me with this? Also, I'm finding it very difficult to translate MongoDB queries pertaining to DictionaryField to a MongoEngine query. Could you point to some tutorial that I could use for the same?

Comment: Looks like a bug - `$rename` doesn't seem to be supported - so open a ticket for that one.  You can still can achieve this though by doing a raw query - http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries

Comment: Thanks for that! I have submitted the [issue](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/595). Could you tell me how I could do the rename based on the raw query?

Comment: See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/ I haven't tested but something like this: `JListInputFile.objects.update(__raw__={"$rename": {"content.old_name": "content.new_name"}})`